# Apache Camel: Set 'description' for Processor using Java DSL

Tags: apache-camel

I can add a custom `id` and `description` to a `<log>` or most other types of processor in XML like this:

```
<log message="Hello" id="logId">
  <description>Description of logging</description>
</log>
```

I've tried to do a similar thing with Java DSL:

```
from("direct:1")
  .log("Hello")
  .id("logId")
  .description("Description of logging")
```

But the description is applied to the route, not the processor. (The `routeId()` method is provided to apply the `id` to the route instead of the processor.)

Looking through the Camel source code, `ProcessorDefinition`'s definition of `id()` has a bunch of code to apply it to the last block or output, preceded by this comment:

```
// set it on last output as this is what the user means to do
// for Block(s) with non empty getOutputs() the id probably refers
//  to the last definition in the current Block
```

There is no similar definition of `description()` in `ProcessorDefinition`, so this simpler method is inherited from `OptionalIdentifiedDefinition`:

```
public T description(String text) {
    if (text != null) {
        if (description == null) {
            description = new DescriptionDefinition();
        }
        description.setText(text);
    }
    return (T) this;
}
```

It seems to me that the Java DSL does not provide a way to set the `description` for `log` or other processors. Is this true, or did I miss something?

(If it is true, should I work on a patch to improve the DSL?)

Comment: Ah nice spotted, yeah those should be so they work similar. You are welcome to work on a patch / github PR. We love contributions. And we may need a routeDescription like routeId to make it explicit for routes. http://camel.apache.org/contributing

Comment: Thanks. I’ll take a look. If you happen to know where updates should be made to tests and documentation, that would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe do a git grep for routeId and see how it was added (you can find the git commit that added it and see how it was done). For documentation then javadoc is sufficient.

Comment: Great idea, I will take a look as soon as I can. Thanks.

Comment: Has it been implemented already? Still is not possible to set Processor's ID in Camel 3.10.